# Convert a quaternion from one coordinate system to another, which are not orthogonal to each other

Tags: coordinates, quaternion

I found a similar question like this in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818102/convert-quaternion-representing-rotation-from-one-coordinate-system-to-another/18818267

In that question, coordinate system axes could be mapped to one and another directly because the coordinate systems are orthogonal to each other, but in my case the coordinate systems are not orthogonal to each other which prevents it to map directly. How can I convert the quaternion rotation in such case? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the relationship between your coordinate systems? Are they both of the same handedness, just oriented differently?

Comment: Yes they are same handed. But they change their relative orientation dynamically.

Comment: And how are you representing the relationship between the coordinate systems? As a quaternion, [similar to this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/143424/39518)?

Comment: Yes. A separate coordinate system(like a world coordinate system) is used to get the orientation of the above mentioned coordinate systems.